# Layer raster data (I think its *.png since it have transparency) on top of each other

Tags: html

I just made my first code from scratch and got stuck. I want to display two images on top of each other (two raster tiles from google maps containing terrain and roads).

But this is as far as I have reached so far. Any tip what Im doing wrong here?

*(I have a Google Maps API key but dont wanna display it here yet - if you wonder - its only valid for a certain number of views and I havnt learned to restrict it yet)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>My first Code Google Map</title>

</head>

<body>
<h1> My first Code Google Map</h1>

<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=57.70886926817119, 11.984633616007413&zoom=13&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:L%7C57.70886926817119,  11.984633616007413&key=myAPIkey"


<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=57.70886926817119, 11.984633616007413&zoom=13&size=512x512&maptype=terrain&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:L%7C57.70886926817119,  11.984633616007413&key=myAPIkey"


alt="Google Map Hybrid" style="width: 505px" 
/>

</body>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: Your markup is currently invalid, you never close your first image tag.

Comment: I only see the first map tile (roadmap) but the second one (terrain) doesnt seem to display at all. Just started learning so not sure what to look for to learn this.

Comment: What is a markup?

Comment: Markup is basically a structure of writing used to convey data, in this case HTML (HyperText **Markup** Language)

Comment: Asking since I have zero experience and cant find an answer through google. Perhaps anyone have any suggestion what I actually missed in my code?